# Why do children wear crowns on Shavuot?

Tags: minhag, clothing, minor-katan-child, shavuos, malchut-royalty

Here in Israel, the tradition is for young children to wear flower crowns to celebrate Shavuot. (Along with the obligatory white shirts.) See my twins:

[image: Children wearing rings around the crowns of their heads made out of fresh flowers]

Why is this? Is it related to Shabbat 88A ??

> Rav Simoi expounded: "When Klal Yisrael said 'Na'aseh' before saying 'Nishma,' 600,000 Malachei HaShareis came to each and every member of Klal Yisrael and crowned him with two crowns - one corresponding to 'Na'aseh' and one corresponding to 'Nishma.'"
>   ([Shabbos 88a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=88&format=pdf))

But on the other hand, what about the general prohibition (minhag?) against wearing crowns since the destruction of the Temple. Eg Brides and bridegrooms no longer wear crowns...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch (OC 560:4) states regarding the prohibition on wearing crowns after the destruction of the Temple:

> וכן גזרו על עטרות חתנים, שלא להניח כלל, ושלא יניח החתן בראשו שום כליל, שנאמר: הסר המצנפת והרם העטרה ([יחזקאל כא, לא](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1221.htm#31)); וכן גזרו על עטרות הכלה, אם היא של כסף, אבל של גדיל מותר לכלה; ודוקא לחתן וכלה, אבל בשאר כל אנשים ונשים לא גזרו.‏
>   And so they decreed about groom's crowns that they should not be worn at all, and that the groom not wear on his head any adornment, for it says ([Ezekiel 12:31](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1221.htm#31)), "The mitre shall be removed, and the crown taken off." They also enacted about the bride's crowns, if it is of silver [to not be worn], but if it is of cloth then it is permitted. **And only for brides and grooms [was this prohibited], but for all other men and women they did not prohibit.** (translation and emphasis mine)

So there should be no problem wearing these crowns.

(See also Tosfot Gittin 7a s.v. עטרות and Tosfot Shabbat 59a s.v. ולא.)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Do you think the custom is a reflection of Shabbat 88A or from somewhere else?

Comment: @LarryK Yes, I do think it is from there. Probably a relatively recent custom though.